# Is there a way to remotely build Xamarin.iOS with sdk 6.1 in VS2012?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have an iOS project that was developed for iOS6.1 and I need to be able to build it for both iOS6.1 and iOS7. I updated all tools from Xamarin and upgraded to OSX Mavericks and iOS 7.0.3 on the iPhone. So at this time I have all latest versions.

When I start to debug the project from VS2012, the app that starts on the iPhone is always an iOS7 app. I added the iOS6.1.sdk to Xcode 5 so back on the Windows machine I can select this SDK in VS2012 for compilation.

But it seems that, whatever SDK I choose in the project settings, it always returns:
`-debug -linksdkonly`**-sdk "7.0"**`-targetver "6.1" --abi=armv7` (arguments taken from the mtbserver.log on the building host)

If I build the project with Xamarin Studio on the Mac the behavior is as expecting when changing the version of the SDK.

Is there a way to get around this when building remotely with VS2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a  bit uncommon and it sounds like a bug - you should file it on [bugzilla](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) so it will be confirmed (and fixed if it's the case).

Most people I know install several Xcode side-by-side, i.e. they do not copy an *old* `.sdk` directory into a newer Xcode release.

You might want to try this (the trick is to rename `Xcode.app` before installing the new one) and then set the VS addin to the older (e.g. `Xcode46.app`) directory when you need to build for iOS 6.1.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. I will take a look at this. My thoughts were that when it works in XS it should work the same way via VS. How can I set the VS addin to the older directory?

Comment: You're right if it works with XS it should work with VS too (or it's a bug). I don't have a Windows box but it's likely named "Apple SDK" under "SDK Locations" (like XS).